# Hyperledger Fabric- Failed to generate orderer genesis block

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

- By running ./byfn.sh generate command I am getting error mentioned
  below:

  ```
     INHYKPMAC01-MacBook-Pro:first-network prakriti$ ./byfn.sh generate -c PDM
     Generating certs and genesis block for channel 'PDM' with CLI timeout of '10' seconds and CLI delay of '3' seconds
     Continue? [Y/n] y
     proceeding ...
     /Users/prakriti/Hyperledger/fabric-samples/first-network/../bin/cryptogen

     ##########################################################
     ##### Generate certificates using cryptogen tool #########
     ##########################################################
     + cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml
     org1.example.com
     org2.example.com
     + res=0
     + set +x

     /Users/prakriti/Hyperledger/fabric-samples/first-network/../bin/configtxgen
     ##########################################################
     #########  Generating Orderer Genesis block ##############
     ##########################################################
     CONSENSUS_TYPE=solo
     + '[' solo == solo ']'
     + configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis -channelID byfn-sys-channel -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block
     2019-03-04 13:29:31.572 IST [common/configtx/tool] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
     2019-03-04 13:29:31.588 IST [common/configtx/tool/localconfig] Load -> CRIT 002 Error reading
  ```

  configuration:  While parsing config: yaml: line 311: did not find
  expected key
         + res=1
         + set +x
  Failed to generate orderer genesis block...

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with a "customised" configtx.yaml file?

Either there is some syntax error in the file or a formatting error in the file.  Exact formatting in yaml is important.

If you are working with the standard file - it could be corrupted, so download a new version.

BTW - channel names cannot contain UPPERCASE characters, so your channel name PDM is invalid.  (I haven't tested the scenario of generating a genesis block using uppercase but sooner or later it will cause a problem.)

**EDIT**

I would also check the version of configtxgen to make sure it is the right 1.4.0 version `../bin/configtxgen -version`  (not an old version or a new v2.0 beta version)

Comment: Thank you Sir for resolving my query.

Comment: I am trying to build network by using this link "https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/build_network.html" as a reference but I got stuck at the very start. I will download new version and will give lowercase letters for channel name.